# Find out which people stay in a population/cohort from the base year to last year and the years in between

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns: c

The table contains information about players/team relationships over multiple years (say, 2010 to 2020)

What I want to know is: 
- For starting year, which  players belonged to team Blueberry
- For year 2, who of the Blueberry players in the starting year still belong to the Blueberry team
-..and so on until the last year studied

A nagging feeling I have is that this is presentable as a single table using only one query.

Please help.

````
Year Player_id team_id
2012 kitliu    Blueberry
2012 bobross   Blueberry
2012 jacksnake Blueberry
2012 kittyjr   Blueberry
2013 kitliu    Blueberry
2013 bobross   Blueberry
2013 narutol   yellow
2014 kitliu    Blueberry
2014 narutol   Red

result:
2012 kitliu    Blueberry
2012 bobross   Blueberry
2012 jacksnake Blueberry
2012 kittyjr   Blueberry
2013 kitliu    Blueberry
2013 bobross   Blueberry
2014 kitliu    Blueberry

result, count retained player/team combos from base year:
Year Count
2012 4
2013 2
2012 1```
````

Comment: Always make a habit of sharing sample I/O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate the players from the base year.  Then use this to check that there are no gaps:

```
select team, year, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by team, player_id order by year) as seqnum
      from t
      where year >= 2012
     ) t
where year = 2012 + seqnum - 1
group by team, year;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=836e041c78c1882720327023f9362de1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, that was a really elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess below query might help like I did it as an alternate meaning selecting by each year if the player hasnt switched any teams.

```
  SELECT year, playerid, 
  count(distinct teamid) 
   from 
  table t group by year, playerid having 
    playerid,count(distinct teamid) IN (
     Select 
     playerid,count(distinct teamid) group 
     by 
    playerid)
     ;
```

Comment: AND COUNT(*) == number of years to exclude those with a pause probably

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function.

```
SELECT YEAR, PLAYER_ID, TEAM_ID 
FROM
(SELECT YEAR, PLAYER_ID, TEAM_ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PLAYER_ID, TEAM_ID ORDER BY YEAR) AS RN,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TEAM_ID ORDER BY YEAR) AS RNK_YEAR 
FROM YOUR_TABLE)
WHERE RN = RNK_YEAR
```

You can use count and group by to get the count year wise on top of this query.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you:

```
with teamyr(year, playerid, teamid) as
(
select min(year), playerid, teamid
from teams
group by playerid, teamid
)
select t1.year, t1.playerid, t1.teamid
from teamyr t1
where t1.year = (select min(year) from teamyr)
union all
select t2.year, t1.playerid, t1.teamid
from teamyr t1
inner join teams t2 on t2.playerid = t1.playerid and t2.teamid = t1.teamid
and t2.year > t1.year
```